# Acquisition of Chiseled Abdominals

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Steven Pressfield's [Do the work](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10645233-do-the-work) book there is an expression I don't understand (my emphasis):

> Resistance's Greatest Hits
>
> The following is a list, in no particular order, of those activities
>   that most commonly elicit Resistance.
>
> 1. The pursuit of any calling in writing, painting, music, film,
>      dance, or any creative art, however marginal or unconventional.
> 2. The launching of any entrepreneurial venture or enterprise,
>      for profit or otherwise.
>
> [...]
>
> 5. Any activity whose aim is the acquisition of **chiseled abdominals**.

Pressfield's resistance is sum total of all behaviors that prevent artists from working (incl. but not limited to laziness). I understand *chiseled* and *abdominals*, but I don't understand what activity he means here.

What activities does the author mean in item 5?

Comment: The author means working out (going to the gym, e.g.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working out - "chiseled" here means fit, or as Merriam-Webster puts it:

> formed or crafted as if with a chisel: *chiseled* good looks, a *chiseled* essay, a *chiseled* physique (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chiseled)

So basically, you resist doing crunches and other exercises even though you want chiseled abdominal muscles, because it's hard work, just like art.